# How to display url with parameter in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, resultset

I am working on an application. I got URL & result
http://localhost/mydss/result/search

When I query with the keyword "radha", getting a result works fine.

However, when I type URL  http://localhost/mydss/result/search/radha I do not get any result.

How should parameters be passed to the URL?

**home.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('result/search');?>" method = "post" name="search" id="search">

   <section class="s_form">
     <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search" name="search" autocomplete="off" value="">
     <button type="submit" class="btn search_button gray"><span class="i_search_g">&nbsp;</span></button></form>
```

**Result.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Result extends CI_Controller {    
function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();

   $this->load->model('result_model','',TRUE);
 }

function search()
{
    $keyword    =   $this->input->get_post('search', TRUE);

    $data['keyword'] = $keyword;
    $data['results']    =   $this->result_model->search($keyword);

    $this->load->view('result',$data);
}}
```

Comment: Your question is absolutely pointless..

Comment: @Svetlio What is solution of this question??

Comment: What is the question ? You have url > you want url .. You don't show any code.. If you have the 1st url working the second should work as well.. but your question is absurd without showing anything from your code..

Comment: @Svetlio i am adding code. plz give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You would get your answer like this;

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Result extends CI_Controller {


    public function index() {

    }

    public function search($query="radha"){

    }


}
```

But this is not great for a search query as CodeIgniter will restrict what you can search for in the query string.

It's better for searching query's like this;

http://localhost/mydss/result/search?q=radha

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Result extends CI_Controller {


    public function index() {

    }

    public function search(){
       $query = $this->input->get("q");
    }


}
```

Comment: There is no point of writing code when the question doesn't provide the original code + its problem..

Comment: @Svetlio I added code to help the guy out - You might not understand his problem but I do

Answer (score 0):

For get this type of url you need to add jquery code on `home.php`

```
# add here jquery file...
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var action = $('#search').val() ? $('#search').val() : "";
        $("#search-form").attr("action", "<?php echo base_url();?>result/search/" + action);
    });
});
</script>
```

And slightly change in your form tag. Chang `id search` to `search-form`.

```
<form action="" method = "post" name="search" id="search-form">
```

When you click on submit button then it takes the value of `input field` and puts in form action.

And finally on **Controller**. You can call like this -

```
public function search($keyword = null)
{

    $data['keyword'] = $keyword;
    $data['results']    =   $this->result_model->search($keyword);

    $this->load->view('result',$data);
}
```